# Include a page's "category" in its URL

Tags: categories, permalinks, slug, title

My site is for landing pages, not a blog - so it contains pages, not posts.

I want URLs like this:

> https://www.example.com/shoes/nike-sport-super-red
>
> https://www.example.com/shoes/adidas-running-black-mens

So a page's category would be "shoes" and the slug would be "nike-sport-super-red".

What I did:

- Wordpress doesn't support categories/tags for pages, so I installed a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-tag-pages) that adds this functionality
- I went to `Settings > Permalinks` and changed it to a custom structure: `/%category%/%postname%/`

But my URLs still do not show the category, only the slug:

> https://www.example.com/nike-sport-super-red

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: That permalink setting is used with the standard Posts (post type `post`) and will not be used with Pages (post type `page`). And actually, why not just create your pages as Posts? That way, you'd get the permalinks in the structure you preferred, all without having to use a plugin or custom code to make the permalinks work.

Comment: @SallyCJ I thought "posts" were used solely for blog posts, whereas a "page" is used for static/dynamic pages?

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the default behavior. But pages also by default have no Categories because pages can be categorized by parent-child relationship, so it's probably better if you categorize your pages in that way. E.g. Create a page `shoes` and add `nike-sport-super-red` as a child of `shoes`. Easy, no plugins, no custom code and the pages would keep its proposed purpose of serving "static" content.